# How do I write to Kafka using pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to write to Kafka using PySpark.
I got stuck on stage zero:

```
[Stage 0:>                                                          (0 + 8) / 9]
```

Then I get a timeout error:

`org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.`

Code is:

```
import os
os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--packages
 org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.2.0 pyspark-shell'

from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

def main():
    spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").appName("Spark CSV Reader")
     .getOrCreate();

    dirpath =  os.path.abspath(sys.argv[1])
    os.chdir(dirpath)

    mySchema = StructType([
     StructField("id", IntegerType()),StructField("name", StringType()),\
     StructField("year", IntegerType()),StructField("rating", DoubleType()),\
     StructField("duration", IntegerType())   ])
    streamingDataFrame = spark.readStream.schema(mySchema)
     .csv('file://' + dirpath + "/" )

    streamingDataFrame.selectExpr("CAST(id AS STRING) AS key",
     "to_json(struct(*)) AS value").\
      writeStream.format("kafka").option("topic", "topicName")\
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")\
      .option("checkpointLocation", "./chkpt").start()
```

I am running HDP 2.6.

Comment: You're running Spark which is **distributed**, but only writing to a `localhost` Kafka Broker...? By the way HDF includes Kafka, where HDP does not

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to yarn butr same problem. I get `connection refused` when I test Kafka so I expect it is that.

Comment: Changed what to YARN? `kafka.bootstrap.servers` needs to point to a Kafka cluster... I highly doubt each of your Spark executors are also in a Kafka Cluster

Comment: The "thing that's wrong" is that `localhost:9092` needs to be the *external address* (ideally more than one) of a Kafka broker

Comment: Yes thanks, changed `kafka.bootstrap.servers` and it worked. Put an answer and I will accept.

Comment: Just wanted to know one thing, @schoon when you write into kafka using selectExpr. is this going to be in the JSON format?

Comment: @AjayKumar sorry 3 years ago can't even remember writing this qn!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, Spark runs on multiple machines, and it is highly unlikely that all these machines will be Kafka brokers.

Use the external address(es) for the Kafka cluster

```
.option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "<kafka-broker-1>:9092,<kafka-broker-2>:9092")\
```

Comment: so for localhost the option will be :

        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "127.0.0.1:9092")

and it doesn't matter how many broker do I have? though in my case I have only one broker

Comment: If you've ran Kafka and Zookeeper locally, Spark master set to local, then yes, either localhost or 127.0.0.1.... If you have multiple brokers on one machine, you can still list localhost for additional brokers, but you need a different port

Comment: Will it be fine if I use only to declare master when I am creating the spark session or I need to explicitly mention when I am writing to Kafka?

Comment: The Spark master is completely unrelated to Kafka. For example, `spark-shell --master` or `spark-submit --master`.

Comment: @cricket_007 can you please look into the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50762812/write-to-kafka-from-the-structured-spark-streaming-using-localhost-server