# Write to Kafka From the Structured Spark Streaming using localhost server

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am developing structured Spark stream application where after analysis did I finally write output to Kafka. The schema of the dataframe is

```
root
 |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |-- value: string (nullable = true)
```

The code for writing to Kafka is

```scala
query = testDataFrame \
    .writeStream \
    .format("kafka") \
    .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "127.0.0.1:9092") \
    .option("topic", output_topic) \
    .option("checkpointLocation", ./tmp") \
    .start()
```

After executing this code, I don't get any error and unfortunately, I don't get anything when I run the Kafka consumer command from the terminal:

```
$KAFKA_HOME/bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic output_topic --from-beginning
```

Please noted that both Kafka and Zookeeper run locally.

Command I used to submit the project:

```
bin/spark-submit --master local --packages org.apache.spark:spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.3.0,org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:1.0.0 pathtoPythonClass
```

Any idea where I am doing error or any kind of help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of Kafka if I write to console, I get the expected output

Comment: Please show how testDataFrame is created

Comment: testDataFrame = df2.selectExpr("CAST(sepal_length_in_cm AS STRING) AS key","to_json(struct(*)) AS value")

Comment: @cricket_007 is it dependent on the packages while submitting the application? Do I give the all required packages? Please have a look

Comment: If you're not getting errors about packages, then no. I don't really use Spark and Kafka together, though

Comment: @cricket_007 I think the problem is not with the Kafka rather it is with Spark. No matter whether I write to Kafka/CSV it is not working for me. I post another question for CSV file here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50775175/found-nothing-in-spark-metadata