# Found nothing in _spark_metadata

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I am trying to read CSV files from a specific folder and write same contents to other CSV file in a different location on the local pc for learning purpose. I can read the file and show the contents on the console. However, if I want to write it to another CSV file at the specified output directory I get a folder named "_spark_metadata" which contain nothing inside.

I paste the whole code here step by step:

## creating Spark Session:

```
spark = SparkSession \
.builder \
.appName('csv01') \
.master('local[*]') \
.getOrCreate();

spark.conf.set("spark.sql.streaming.checkpointLocation", <String path to checkpoint location directory> )
userSchema = StructType().add("name", "string").add("age", "integer")
```

## Read from CSV file

```
df = spark \
.readStream \
.schema(userSchema) \
.option("sep",",") \
.csv(<String path to local input directory containing CSV file>)
```

## Write to CSV file

```
df.writeStream \
.format("csv") \
.option("path", <String path to local output directory containing CSV file>) \
.start()
```

In "String path to local output directory containing CSV file" I only get a folder _spark_metadata which contains no CSV file.

Any help on this is highly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't use readStream to read from static data. You use that to read from a directory where files **are added into** that folder.

You only need `spark.read.csv`

Comment: I do that because I want to learn spark streaming part, and please be noted if I write to console df.writeStream \
    .format("console") \
    .option("truncate", "false") \
    .start() \
    .awaitTermination()
.... it shows the contents of the file but the problem is with the writeStream to csv file.

Comment: if you do only spark.read.csv it is not the streaming dataset/dataframe

Comment: Again, in order for data to be added to the input stream, CSV files currently existing in the folder will not be read. They must be moved into the folder after Spark starts

Comment: My bad, so the problem is my lack of understanding on reading the CSV file, not the writing. Yes, now it is written to CSV file as well  :) but can you please explain why the output shows in the console format

Comment: Not really sure. I think the console output is only meant for debugging the stream. It doesn't keep track of the output location or checkpoints

Comment: Since you're asking about Kafka before, you can look at this https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir or Fluentd or Filebeat or Logstash

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172814/discussion-between-khan-hafizur-rahman-and-cricket-007).

Comment: so for Kafka, if I send the data to Kafka topic after Spark starts will not it be able to write into the output Kafka topic?

Comment: You should be able to send Kafka data before or after Spark starts. The Kafka offsets are independent of Spark processing